# Police have seized phone regarding sent emails

Tags: ip, isp

The police in UK have my phone. I have sent some emails I shouldn't have to an ex. I have deleted the gmail account they were sent from.  The phone police have isn't the one they were sent from. I have disabled the SIM (reported as lost to Vodafone) and have a new IP from the ISP from which the phone was connected through.

What are the chances of it being traced back to me?

Comment: With the cooperation of Google and your ISP, law enforcement can easily trace an email that you sent back to you, without having the device that you sent it from.  All it takes is for Google to provide law enforcement with the IP address that you used to access their Gmail service when you sent the email (which they can easily parse from their logs), then for your ISP to check which of their customers they assigned this IP address to at that time, and provide this to law enforcement.

Comment: Even if the gmail account was removed 3 months ago, I tried sending an email to the removed account and it bounced back

Comment: Yes.  We have no way of knowing how long Google retains log records for accounts that have been removed.  In some jurisdictions, they may even be required to retain these log records.

Comment: The duplicate explains the log data issue and time

Comment: Hindering a police investigation, perverting the course of justice, destroying evidence, there might be no need to actually read your messages. Any email you ever sent to me is stored with _my_ ISP and on my computer. That’s enough.